# Powershell Script to Run at startup as administrator

Tags: powershell, automation, startup

I want to achieve the following:

1. Run a command in command prompt
2. Restart the system
3. Run Different command
4. Restart the system
5. Continue the execution of rest of the power shell script

These are to help me patch very big systems that may take hours, hence I want them to continue without login and run as an administrator to finish up all the tasks.

Comment: powershell dsc is what you are looking for, or other similar configuration management things

Comment: _"I want to achieve the following: [...]"_ Good to know, thanks for informing the internet about that. Do you want to ask a question?

Comment: an admin user will open the cmd in elevated mode only. But what kind of solution you are actually looking for . DSC approach or normal script based approach. Probably you can use [Windows Patching Module](https://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Use_Windows_Patching_PowerShell_Module)

Comment: PowerShell workflows can be written to continue after a reboot.

Comment: @Clijsters I did ask it as a question,But Adminstrator modified the question though.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with powershell by creating a script that:

- Executes a command
- Set autologon to use admin credentials in regedit
- Set the script to call itself on reboot using ScheduleTasks allowing you to set the runlevel as highests and thus run the script as admin
- Restart computer

The script will then call itself, and you can use parameter passing / regedit to deteremine what stage of the process you are at.

Comment: Can you please help me with that?

Comment: In what way do you need help with that? Would my answer help you achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: Looks like this will help me,Could you please guide me on how to achieve this.

Comment: Create a powershell ps1 file, put your command in there, then set the autologon reg creds at HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon, create new scheduled task using New-ScheduledTaskAction and New-ScheduledTaskTrigger, the action being running the script and trigger being at log on. Then register the task using Register-ScheduledTask